# % sign in context of WordPress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

What does the % sign mean in this context. What is the proper terminology for continued understanding of what is happening here? What are the % signs called in this context?

```
register_post_type(
            self::$post_type_artwork,//hfw_artwork
            array(
                'label' => 'Artwork',
                [
                    'name'          => 'Artwork',
                    'singular_name' => 'Artwork',
                ],
                'public'    => TRUE,
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
                'rewrite' => [
                    'slug' => 'artwork/%show_category%',
                ],
                /*'taxonomies' => array('shop_category'),*/
                /*'taxonomies' => array('shop_category','category'),*/
                'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
                'has_archive'         => true
            
            )
        );
```

```
%show_category%
```

Comment: Since this is part of the rewrite slug configuration for this CPT, I would assume it is meant to be a placeholder similar to those available in the general permalink settings (https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/settings-permalinks-screen/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, the `%` character is typically used as a placeholder in URL routing patterns. It's a way to represent the dynamic parts of the URL. The placeholder is then replaced with a dynamic value when the page is accessed.